# In Laravel, what is meant by the term "clear compiled class"

Tags: laravel-4, phpstorm

I'm trying to use a service class in Laravel called ide-helper. It provides auto completion into PHPStorm. it is not functioning as expected. I have been advised that I should run php artisan clear-compiled.

what does the term "clear compiled" mean ?

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdoc-generation-for-laravel-facades

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses an optimized class loader for better performance.

The command `php artisan clear-compiled` deletes the following 2 files:

1. `bootstrap/compiled.php` Created when you optimize classes.
2. `app/storage/meta/services.json` This file is created as Laravel tries to optimize the loading of the service providers your application uses.

For more Information on performance optimizing also see http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/60/optimizing-the-framework-for-better-performance